# How to center a Node in Graphviz

Tags: graphviz

I have this graph:

```
digraph Database {
graph [bb="0 0 180 96",
    fontname="Verdana-Bold",
    fontsize=14,
    labeljust=r,
    labelloc=t,
    margin=12,
    nodesep=0.5555555555555556,
    pad=0.5,
    rankdir=RL,
    ranksep=0.3472222222222222,
    sep=0.05,
    splines=spline
];
node [fixedsize=true,
    fontname=Verdana,
    fontsize=11,
    height=40,
    label="correct me",
    labelloc=c,
    margin=0,
    shape=box,
    style=rounded,
    width=100
];
Node1   [fontsize=14.0,
    height=1.3333333333333333,
    label="Here a long enough
example of a node.
Unfortunately, the text
won't remain in the box",
        width=2.4944932725694446];
}
```

which produces this output:
[image: single Node output]
Why is that so? (not sure why picture itself is so small)
The text/label should be centered (`labelloc=c`) but isn't.

Comment: The picture is so small because of `margin=12` graph attribute. Remove it and the excessive borders will go away

Answer (score 2):

You are using [`fixedsize=true`](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html#d:fixedsize):

> If true, the node size is specified by the values of the width and
>   height attributes only and is **not** expanded to contain the text label.

Therefore, if you want to be sure that the label is contained within the node shape, do not use `fixedsize=true`.

However, this doesn't explain why the label isn't centered, and makes me wonder about the version of graphviz you are using. Tools like http://viz-js.com/ display the label centered (select png output).

On a side note, [`labelloc=c`](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html#d:labelloc) is for **vertical** alignment of the label.

Comment: good point. I use a current version, not the "stable" release. Might want to check with stable version.

Comment: And special thanks for highlighting the labelled for vertical alignment.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this code is created with some "tool" that adds lots of nonsensical stuff to the code. `graphviz`, if instructed in clear and simple terms, doesn't have that problem:

```
digraph Database 
{
    Node1 [ shape = box, style = rounded,
    label="Here a long enough example of a node.\nUnfortunately, the text won't remain in the box"]
}
```

yields

[image]

How does this help you? If you want to create a graph with your tool, you will need to find out how to fine tune the settings in a way that it does what you want. Or you start (which would be my recommendation) working with `graphviz` directly. Then, you could start with the basics and move to the more complicated formatting options only when and to the extent actually needed.